# Finding the maximum $lcm$ of a set of numbers with sum $n$

Tags: number-theory, computability

Consider all possible values for $(a_1,\ldots,a_n)$ (where each $a_i$ may be a positive integer or 0) when 
$a_1 + \cdots + a_n = n$.

Consider $(a_j,\ldots,a_k)$ the values in $(a_1,\ldots,a_n)$ which are non-zero.

Given a set of values for all $a_i$, $j\le i\le k$ can we check whether they maximise $\operatorname{lcm}(a_j,\ldots,a_k)$ without testing all other cases?

Is there a computationally viable way  to always pick values for all $a_i$ which maximise $\operatorname{lcm}(a_1,\ldots,a_k)$?

Comment: If you have $n$ positive integers and their sum is $n$, there is little choice

Comment: I should clarify that, but I meant up to $n$ positive integers with zero being a possibility on all.

Comment: Note that $\operatorname{lcm}(0,x)=0$

Comment: again, my oversight. modified to express the question more accurately

Comment: OEIS is wonderful for questions like this  I computed values up to $a_9$ by hand and searched the database.  I got the one sequence I cite.

Answer (score 3):

The sequence is given in [OEIS A000793](https://oeis.org/A000793).  It is called Landau's function and starts $$1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 6, 12, 15, 20, 30, 30, 60, 60, 84, 105, 140, 210, 210,\\
 420, 420, 420, 420, 840, 840, 1260, 1260, 1540, 2310, 2520, 4620, 4620,\\
 5460, 5460, 9240, 9240, 13860, 13860, 16380, 16380, 27720, 30030,\\
 32760, 60060, 60060, 60060, 60060, 120120$$
It grows about as $e^{\sqrt{n \log(n)}}$.  A number of references are given.

Comment: I'm sorry, but this seems incorrect. For example, when $n = 9$, $4+5 = 9$ and $lcm(4,5) = 20$ which is the maximum $lcm$ you can get for integers adding up to 9. And 4 and 5 don't appear in that sequence.

Comment: Uhm, I see that $8=3+5$ gives us $15$, but how do you get lcm (not product) $24$ with sum $9$? I get only $lcm(5,4)=20$

Comment: @user3129805:  you are correct.  It is for the product of the terms, not the LCM.  I found the right sequence